# проблема: не зависит от padding, от чего зависит?

Tags: html, css, scss

`.content-body` должен выполнить по `style padding`.
На самом деле не тот, как кажется.

[image: 1]

```
.content-body {
    display: block;
    padding: 40px 140px 40px 140px;
    .margin-60 {
        padding-right: 60px;
        padding-left: 0;
        position: relative;
        font-family: 'Prata', sans-serif;
        .chapter {
            color: $hoverTitle;
            font-family: 'Prata', sans-serif;
        }
        .line-spacer {
            margin-top: 30px;
            padding-top: 30px;
            border-top: 1px dashed $grey;
        }
        .menu-tags {
            .tag {
                display: inline-block;
                margin-top: 10px;
                padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;      
                width: 20%;       
                font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
                color: $grey;
                font-size: 14px;
                line-height: 24px;
                text-align: center;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Код добавьте...

Comment: А `HTML` мы сами додумаем/высмотрим_на_картинке? И лучше `CSS` выложить, дабы избежать банально кривой генерации препроцессора.

Comment: а как без препроцессов, у которых имеют важные значения?

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему: переставить из min-width: 997px в max-width:997px.
Будь внимательны!